# Get Id from database in a listview onclick

Tags: android, database, android-listview

I have this class, that gets the data from the database and shows in a listview.

Is there a way to get the Id from the database and toast it?

Now the toast is returning: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4180c088`

```
 public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity { 

 private SQLiteAdapter
 mySQLiteAdapter;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

     mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
     mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

     Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
     startManagingCursor(cursor);

     String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_NOME,SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID};
     int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text,R.id.id};

     SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

     listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

     listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                 long id) {
                //GET ID FROM DATABASE
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //THIS TOAST IS RETURNING "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4180c088"
         }
     });

     mySQLiteAdapter.close();
 } }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the `id` parameter of `onItemClick()`:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), id + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

---

For future reference you are currently trying to use an entire Cursor as a String, you want to select a column like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getLong(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

(For a SimpleCursorAdapter the first column is always the `_id` column, hence `getLong(0)`.)

Comment: Thank you a lot, the second snippet is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: I'm glad I could help! But did you try the first one? It should be a much faster way to get the same id.

Comment: I tried both, but maybe, in my case I'll need more than just the id! Anyway, thank you again.